# find the reason I am getting zeros in a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am sifting through a data set and hope to assign string values to integers. When this is done I get some values equalling 0 in my vector and I am not sure where they are coming from. I am taking out the observations with blank values for this one variable and hoping to plot the rest. Any thoughts?

```
TexasMLSCounties=TexasMLSCounties[!TexasMLSCounties$X.2==" ",]

MLS=TexasMLSCounties$X.2
MLS=MLS[!TexasMLSCounties$X.2==""]
dput(MLS)
MLSNumber=integer(length=length(MLS))

for (i in 1:length(MLS)) {
  if(is.na(MLS))
    MLS=FALSE
  else{
    if(MLS[i]=="NTREIS")
      MLSNumber[i]=1
    else if(MLS[i]=="HARMLS")
      MLSNumber[i]=2
    else if(MLS[i]=="SABOR")
      MLSNumber[i]=3
    else if(MLS[i]=="ACTRIS")
      MLSNumber[i]=4 
    else if(MLS[i]=="CTXMLS")
      MLSNumber[i]=5
  }
  
}
```

---

```
dput(MLS)
c("MLS", "NTREIS", "HARMLS", "NTREIS", "SABOR", "HARMLS", "ACTRIS", 
"ACTRIS", "SABOR", "ACTRIS", "NTREIS", "HARMLS", "NTREIS", "ACTRIS", 
"ACTRIS", "NTREIS", "HARMLS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "HARMLS", 
"ACTRIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "CTXMLS", 
"NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "ACTRIS", "HARMLS", "NTREIS", 
"NTREIS", "SABOR", "HARMLS", "ACTRIS", "CTXMLS", "ACTRIS", "NTREIS", 
"ACTRIS", "NTREIS", "HARMLS", "NTREIS", "ACTRIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", 
"NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "SABOR", 
"NTREIS", "SABOR", "NTREIS", "ACTRIS", "SABOR?", "CTXMLS", "ACTRIS", 
"HARMLS", "NTREIS", "ACTRIS", "NTREIS", "SABOR", "HARMLS", "SABOR", 
"ACTRIS", "NTREIS", "HARMLS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", 
"HARMLS", "NTREIS", "CTXMLS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "ACTRIS?", 
"ACTRIS?", "ACTRIS?", "ACTRIS?", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", 
"NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", 
"ACTRIS", "HARMLS", "HARMLS", "NTREIS", "CTXMLS", "HARMLS", "HARMLS", 
"HARMLS", "NTREIS", "ACTRIS", "SABOR", "NTREIS", "NTREIS", "NTREIS"
)
```

Comment: `if` evaluates a logical vector of length one. You are passing it `as.na(MLS)`. `is.na` is a vectorized function, so it's outputting a logical vector that is the same length as `MLS`, which I am assuming has a length greater than one. However, `if` is only evaluating the first element of that logical vector.

Comment: Its not a vector of all zeros. I will change my question, but I get zeros in the vector

Comment: You do not have a condition to change the value of `MLSNumber` when `MLS=="MLS"`. Since you created a vector of all zeros, you are only replaced those zeros where you have specified conditions. Where you have not, it remains zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `MLS`, some values end with a question mark, `"?"`.

```
unique(MLS)
#[1] "MLS"     "NTREIS"  "HARMLS"  "SABOR"   "ACTRIS" 
#[6] "CTXMLS"  "SABOR?"  "ACTRIS?"
```

A solution is to first remove all non alphabetic characters.

```
MLS <- gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", MLS)
unique(MLS)
#[1] "MLS"    "NTREIS" "HARMLS" "SABOR"  "ACTRIS" "CTXMLS"
```

Note that the first value is `"MLS"`, and that this is not matched by any of the values in the `for` loop.

As for the loop, there are better ways, below is one based on `match`.

```
MLSNumber <- integer(length = length(MLS))

for (i in seq_along(MLS)) {
  if(MLS[i]=="NTREIS")
    MLSNumber[i]=1
  else if(MLS[i]=="HARMLS")
    MLSNumber[i]=2
  else if(MLS[i]=="SABOR")
    MLSNumber[i]=3
  else if(MLS[i]=="ACTRIS")
    MLSNumber[i]=4 
  else if(MLS[i]=="CTXMLS")
    MLSNumber[i]=5
}
```

And a simpler.

```
MLSNumber2 <- integer(length = length(MLS))    
MLSTable <- c("NTREIS", "HARMLS", "SABOR", "ACTRIS", "CTXMLS")
i <- match(MLS, MLSTable)
MLSNumber2[!is.na(i)] <- i[!is.na(i)]
```

Compare the results:

```
all.equal(MLSNumber, MLSNumber2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`MLSnumber` is a vector of zeros to start:

```
MLSNumber=integer(length=length(MLS))

MLSNumber
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [46] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [91] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You are looping through the index of `MLS`. Your first condition is coded incorrectly, but I assume it should read:

```
if (is.na(MLS[i])) # correct
if (is.na(MLS)) # incorrect
```

`if` evaluates a logical vector of length **one**. You are passing it `as.na(MLS)`. `is.na` is a vectorized function, so it's outputting a logical vector that is the same length as `MLS`. However, `if` is only evaluating the first element of that logical vector:

```
if (is.na(c(F, NA, NA, NA)) {print("A")}
Warning message:
In if (is.na(c(F, NA, NA, NA))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Since your `if` statement is only really evaluating `is.an(MLS[1])` that condition is always `FALSE` because `MLS[1]` is not `NA`. So your loop is always entering the `else` condition.

Within your `else` condition, you have several issues noted by @RuiBarradas. For example when `i=1` then `MLS[i]` is `"MLS"`. You do not have a condition for what to do in this instance. So it exits your `if/else` clause. The value of that index is never changed in `MLSNumber`, so it remains zero.